# How to convert mysql datetime to client country time in flash(as3)?

Tags: mysql, actionscript-3

for example we have a time stored in mysql:

`2010/12/13 12:00:23` - this is the server time, how do I convert it to user country time via flash(as3)?

is there any function that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should know what's the time zone is your server time in.

   ```
   var serverTime:String = "2010/12/13 12:00:23";
   var serverDate:Date = new Date( serverTime );
   var serverTimeZone:int = 6;//Assume server is in UTC+6
   ```
2. Get the user's time zone offset, **use `-`**.

   ```
   var userDate:Date = new Date();
   var userTimeOffset:Number = -userDate.getTimezoneOffset();//use -for the oppsite!!
   ```
3. Calculate.

   ```
   var finalTs:Number = serverDate.valueOf() - serverTimeZone * 3600000 + userTimeOffset * 60000;
   var finalDate:Date = new Date( serverTs );//I'm in UTC+8, so finalDate will be Mon Dec 13 14:00:23
   ```